# Compare 2 arrays with wildcards in powershell

Tags: powershell

Say we have 2 .txt-files like so:

users.txt

```
user.name1
user.name2
admin.name1
admin.name2
```

shares.txt

```
\\someserver\somefolder\user.name1
\\someserver\somefolder\user.name2
\\someserver\someotherfolder\admin.name1
\\someotherserver\somefolder\admin.name2
\\someplaceelse\somefolder\no.name
```

I want to compare these 2 points of data to show only the rows in "shares.txt" that match a name in "users.txt". I figure we need to use some sort of wildcardsearch as the username is always included in the uncpath but will not be exactly the same, here is an example of what i have tried so far without success

```
$users = Get-Content ".\users.txt"
$shares = Get-Content ".\shares.txt"
foreach ($line in $users)
{
if ("*$line*" -like "$shares")
}
Write-Host "this line matches $line"
}
}
```

Comment: `Select-String -Path ".\shares.txt" -Pattern (Get-Content ".\users.txt") -SimpleMatch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($line in $users)
{
if ($shares -like "*$line*")
{
Write-Host "$($shares | where {$_ -like "*$line*"}) this line matches $line"
}
}
```

to get the intended information the current value of the loop must be included in the search.

The problem in your code was that like operator only allows wild cards on the right side of the expression. So the matching must happen the other way around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Comment: this does indeed do what i intended so please let it stay, the problem here was that i did not use current value in my query "$_". simple mistake to do. I also needed to add "*$line*" as there might be some lingo at the end of the UNCpath aswell.